# hi can help me in this issu wth database whith django

Tags: django

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

how can resolv this issue .im alrady install psycopg2 in my vertualenv

Comment: If that happens and you're absolutely sure you've installed `psycopg2`, then your Django installation is not using that virtualenv.

Comment: Use `pip freeze` command to verify that required dependencies installed properly.

Comment: @HabeebAlbedalkareem I had a similar problem. If you are using Linux the missing package `libpq-dev` may cause the problem. If a different version of `libpq` is installed you have to remove it and install the package `libpq-dev`. `psycopg2` needs the dependency of `libpq-dev`. For building python packages you need `build-essential` as well. However, try activating your virtualenv at first.

Comment: This is duplicate question, would be good to search existing questions first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237842/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-psycopg-module-no-mo

Answer (score 0):

activate your env and do a pip install

cd /path/to/virtualenv

source name-of-vitualenv/bin/activate

pip3 install psycopg2