# Error while deploying app (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url')

Tags: django, deployment

I am using render.com for the deployment of my app but I get the following error :

```
File "/opt/render/project/src/calendar_app/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
Nov 8 09:22:48 PM     import dj_database_url
Nov 8 09:22:48 PM  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

why is that?

Looking if I have the package in my terminal using pip I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from Django>=3.2->dj_database_url) (2023.3)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly you did not install packages on render https://render.com/docs/deploy-django#update-your-app-for-render

Comment: seems like I have all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem like dj-database-url needs to be installed in installed apps.

The usage can be found on pypi, or their respective documentation page.

https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/

Comment: I dont have dj-database-url in installed apps

Comment: @MrJonesBones Have you configured a virtual environment; or are you running this in your global environment? Can you confirm the package is installed in your respective python `site_packages` folder?

Comment: yes I configure a virtual environment, in what folder can I find site_packages?

Comment: @MrJonesBones `<venv folder>/lib/site_packages`, there should be a folder called `dj_database_url`. Have you activated your virtual environment, and installed it there? You can activate your virtual environment by running `<venv folder>/Scripts/activate.<shell extension>`

Comment: yes the folder dj_database_url is there

Comment: since you are uploading it; I *presume* you need to pass a `requirements.txt`, is it in there?

Comment: yep.............

Comment: @MrJonesBones mind uploading your project to github? don't forget to take out secrets! P.S; `Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from Django>=3.2->dj_database_url) (2023.3)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)` makes me think your venv isn't properly activated; it i'm pretty sure the path should point to your virtual env's packages.

Comment: https://github.com/SamLCris/calendar_app

Comment: Hey! I noticed you added your requirements.txt. If the server uses this file to install all relevant packages; there is no `dj_database_url` package...  Can you verify, if `dj_database_url` is installed in site packages of your virtual environment and that the `requirements.txt` you generated actually came from your virtual environment which contains the install?

Comment: yep there is dj_database_url in the venv packages

Comment: yes; but it's not in the `requirements.txt`... This is what your server uses to download packages, no?

Comment: I am getting now : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module

Comment: @MrJonesBones https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423419/18020941

Comment: should I do it in my terminal or the deployer's terminal ?

Comment: @MrJonesBones On the server itself. That is where the error occurs; right?

Comment: the error occurs in the deployer´s website

Comment: the server is live now after adding the files to requirements.txt as you said but I get this message in the browser: Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2023:19:04:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455795/22855282