Unable to use psycopg2 with Postgres in Django
As stated in my question, I am now configuring my djagno project to connect with postgres. The issue i am facing is that, when making migrations, it shows me the following error:
python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
  import psycopg as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 27, in <module>
  import psycopg2 as Database
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
  ...<10 lines>...
  )
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\backend\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
  main()
  ~~~~^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\backend\manage.py", line 18, in main
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
  django.setup()
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
  app_config.import_models()
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
  self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Coding Apps\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1022, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 5, in <module>
  from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 40, in <module>
  class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  ...<123 lines>...
          )
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 143, in __new__
  new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
  value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
  self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
  return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
  conn = self.create_connection(alias)
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
  backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
  return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
File "E:\Coding Apps\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Code\Ecom\Ecom\ecom\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 29, in <module>
  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module
(ecom) 

i have tried literally everything, from adding psql to path to trying to install previous version of psycopg2, but to no avail. I have also ran a dozen session on chatgpt
Can someone help me with this?

The issue boils  down to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg' which in turn comes from DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.. This question needs more information before it can be answered though. Add as text update to question text the following: 1) Versions for Django, Postgres and Python. 2) OS and version. 3) Have you installed psycopg/psycopg2? 4) Are you running this in a virtual environment?

1.) All the versions are the latest 2.) I have installed psycopg2. Do i need psycopg as well? 3.) yes this is a virtual environment

Latest is a relative term, take the time to list the actual versions in use at the time you ran this. Do not leave out the OS and version.

The solution was actually really simple. I had been using Python 3.13, and I downgraded to Python 3.12, created a new virtualenv, and the migrations ran smoothly.

To resolve this PostgreSQL connection issue in Django you can follow this-
First, install the correct PostgreSQL database driver. Use:
pip install psycopg2-binary

If you prefer the regular psycopg2, you'll need the PostgreSQL binaries installed first:
pip install psycopg2

Make sure your settings.py has the correct database configuration:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'put_your_db_name',
        'USER': 'put_your_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'put_your_password', # or use from env
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


This is all correct. The problem i think is that it is not detecting psycopg

did you install psycopg2-binary? if you are using some kind of virtualenv make sure it has the psycopg2-binary installed. Similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423419/1138192

Yes i had installed psycopg2-binary first. When it didn't work i tried psycopg but again to move avail. And yes this was virtual env

Activate your venv and type python. At the command line, what happens when you type import psycopg2? Please bear in mind there is a different between psycopg2 and psycopg. You may want to just use psycopg`, which is version 3, the newer one.
